# PPTP connection: Timeout sending config requests when in eduroam network

Tags: networking, vpn, pptp

trying to connect to a pptp-vpn from within my university network (['eduroam' standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduroam)). connection cannot be established (LCP: Timeout sending Config-Requests). The connection works flawlessly from any other network. I cannot check the logs on the server's side.

I can connect to port 1723 via telnet.

I provide logs both for successful connection attempts (at home, DSL) and unsuccessful ones (at university);  additionally some information about my connection at university (netctl connect profile, ifconfig output, routes) in a gist: https://gist.github.com/Foucl/6b842f94ef5042ba2062

I followed the pptp client diagnosis suggestions and the fault tree there (I am out of links) and have added the iptables mentioned. I could not get hping2 to work (it's not producing any output).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides TCP port 1723, PPTP also uses GRE to transport data. You need firewall permission for GRE to your PPTP endpoint.

Comment: thank you, that seems to be the problem (at a different university that also uses the eduroam specification the connection works). I will report back as soon as I found out why/how my university deviates from the standard here (GRE should be supported). Maybe I will find information that could be useful to other users. If not, I will close the question.

Comment: If you are using linux, you may have to load  the nf_conntrack_proto_gre
and nf_conntrack_pptp kernel modules for certain PPTP/VPN servers. This can be done with: ```$ sudo modprobe nf_conntrack_proto_gre nf_conntrack_pptp```

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 37

Following the instructions of https://superuser.com/a/843285/1782169, I installed firewall-config using [this](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/firewalld/) instructions and added GRE protocol on FedoraWorkstation -> Protocols -> Add -> Other protocol and typing GRE. Now my vpn is working